# war deployment error in Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, war

When I try to deploy a war ( apache airavata-registry.war) I get the error shown below. 
What can be the reason?

Nov 14, 2013 7:41:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Nov 14, 2013 7:41:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: HTMLManager: start: Starting web application '/airavata'
Nov 14, 2013 7:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.airavata.credential.store.servlet.CredentialBootstrapper
edu.uiuc.ncsa.security.core.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Error: could not load configuration
    at edu.uiuc.ncsa.security.servlet.Bootstrapper.contextInitialized(Bootstrapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: edu.uiuc.ncsa.security.core.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Error: No configuration found anyplace. Server startup aborted!
    at edu.uiuc.ncsa.myproxy.oa4mp.client.loader.ClientBootstrapper.getConfigurationLoader(ClientBootstrapper.java:105)
    at org.apache.airavata.credential.store.servlet.CredentialBootstrapper.getConfigurationLoader(CredentialBootstrapper.java:45)
    at edu.uiuc.ncsa.security.servlet.Bootstrapper.contextInitialized(Bootstrapper.java:39)
    ... 30 more

Answer (score 0):

Could you please run a check for a file named "client.xml" at one of the following locations:
 - $USER_HOME/client.xml
 - $USER_HOME/oa4mp/client.xml
 - $USER_DIR/client.xml
 - /var/www/config/client.xml
 - /var/www/config/oa4mp/client.xml.

Referring to the statement at GrepCode, "edu.uiuc.ncsa.myproxy.oa4mp.client.loader.ClientBootstrapper"

"A class required by Tomcat. This is the entry point for loading the configuration file. One feature of this is that it will search for configurations in various default locations using a default file name of client.xml".

Reference:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@edu.uiuc.ncsa.myproxy$oa4mp-client-oauth1@1.0.6@edu$uiuc$ncsa$myproxy$oa4mp$client$loader$ClientBootstrapper.java

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked. I don't have a client.xml in those locations. What should I do?